# No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is configured to handle sign in for the scheme: Identity.Application

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I was trying to change the default id of identity, i did changed the id and instead of using AddIdentity, i used AddIdenityCore and specified 
Default authentication schemes and default sign in and signoutscheme

but i am getting this no IAuthenticationSignInHandler is configured error while registering and signing in from that register method.

await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false); --> error occurred here

```
 IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(ApplicationRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<ApplicationRole>>()
          .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
          .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
          options =>
          {
              options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
              options.LoginPath = new PathString("/user/account/login");
              options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/user/account/accessdenied");
          });
```

Comment: I've Already tried this ans. but not luck. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319749/invalidoperationexception-no-iauthenticationsigninhandler-is-configured-to-hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319749/invalidoperationexception-no-iauthenticationsigninhandler-is-configured-to-hand)

Comment: Are you saying that you added `.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)` and the result was *exactly the same* error?

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes but i just figured out the solution. Instead of using `options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;` , i should use `options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;` using that solved my problem.